# python - how to inflate gzipped, base64d string

Tags: python, base64, gzip

I'm just wondering how is it possible to inflate/decompress a string of text that is a gzipped compressed string that also hase base64 encoding?

For instance, all the python examples seem to focus on opening a file, whereas I want to work on a gzipped string.

Comment: I what oder where these algorithms applied to the input? Do you have a sample?

Comment: As a hint, there are (builtin) python modules called `gzip` and `base64`, they might very well contain all the tools you need ;) Start e.g. at https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base64 and zlib libraries:

```
import base64, zlib
decoded_data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(encoded_data))
```

The gzip module is only for file operations: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html.
It uses zlib for actual compression/decompression.

Comment: You are decompressing before decoding - it should be the other way round. Nobody does base64-encoding and then compresses - they compress and then base64-encode to make it ASCII again.

Answer (score 23):

Under python3, other answers didn't help me but I found this:

```
import base64
import zlib
data = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAHWPwQqCQBCGX0Xm7EFtK+smZBEUgXoLCdMhFtKV3akI8d0bLYmibvPPN3wz00CJxmQnTO41whwWQRIctmEcB6sQbFC3CjW3XW8kxpOpP+OC22d1Wml1qZkQGtoMsScxaczKN3plG8zlaHIta5KqWsozoTYw3/djzwhpLwivWFGHGpAFe7DL68JlBUk+l7KSN7tCOEJ4M3/qOI49vMHj+zCKdlFqLaU2ZHV2a4Ct/an0/ivdX8oYc1UVX860fQDQiMdxRQEAAA=='

json_str = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(data), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode('utf-8')
```

hope this helps

Comment: Great! Other answers didn't helped me too, yours is perfect!
Thanks!

Comment: How can we get string ```"H4sIAAAAAAAAAHWPwQqCQBCGX0Xm7EFtK+smZBEUgXoLCdMhFtKV3akI8d0bLYmibvPPN3wz00CJxmQnTO41whwWQRIctmEcB6sQbFC3CjW3XW8kxpOpP+OC22d1Wml1qZkQGtoMsScxaczKN3plG8zlaHIta5KqWsozoTYw3/djzwhpLwivWFGHGpAFe7DL68JlBUk+l7KSN7tCOEJ4M3/qOI49vMHj+zCKdlFqLaU2ZHV2a4Ct/an0/ivdX8oYc1UVX860fQDQiMdxRQEAAA=="``` back from decompressed string?

Comment: I get this erro: `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check` from this data: `Ch1wdC5saXZlLnVzZXIuaW5pdC9Jbml0UmVxdWVzdBIBMBoAMABgAQ==` How overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

For me the following code worked best (gzip without file)

```
import base64
import gzip

base64_message = # string containing base64 encoded data
base64_bytes = base64_message.encode('utf-8')
message_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
print(gzip.decompress(message_bytes))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GzipFile`in the `gzip` module allows you to provide a `fileobj` argument. If the string is really *gzipped* (ie: it has the proper headers) you can then wrap the string in a `StringIO` object and pass it around

```
import base64
import gzip
from io import StringIO

gzippedstr = fetchgzippedstr()  # wherever it may come from
gzcontent = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(gzippedstr))
b64content = gzcontent.read()
content = base64.b64decode(b64content)
```